# Convergence in Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a sequence of $N$ Bernoulli trials with, with probability of success denoted by $p$, and let $X$ be the number of successes. Show that as $N\rightarrow\infty$, $\frac{X}{N}$ converges in probability to $p$.

I am not sure how to tackle this but I think that as if this occurs then by definition $P\left(\frac{X}{N} - p \geq \varepsilon\right)= 0$, as $N\rightarrow\infty$. How would I show this is through?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the central limit theorem?  Seems as though it's fairly trivial if you are.

Comment: The central limit theorem is overkill.  Yes, you can kill a fly with dynamite.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the case of the central limit theorem in which $X$ is as defined here and $p=1/2$ was proved in the 18th century by Abraham de Moivre.  That falls short of the full central limit theorem, which I think was not proved until around 1930, I think.  But still it's much more than what is needed to answer this. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}$Markov's inequality says if $Y$ is a **non-negative** random variable and $y>0$, then
$$
\Pr(Y\ge y) \le \frac{\E(Y)} y.
$$
(See the bottom of this posting for a proof of Markov's inequality.)

Applying Markov's inequality to $(X-\mu)^2$, where $\mu=\E X$, we get $\Pr((X-\mu)^2\ge d^2)\le \dfrac{\sigma^2}{d^2}$ where $\sigma^2=\var X$. From that we deduce Chebyshev's inequality:
$$
\Pr\left(|X-\mu|\ge d\right)\le \frac{\sigma^2}{d^2}.
$$

For the random variable $X$ defined in the question we have
$$
\E \frac X N = p\qquad\text{and}\qquad \var \frac X N = \frac{p(1-p)} N.
$$
So by Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\Pr\left( \left| \frac X N - p \right| \ge \varepsilon \right) \le \frac{p(1-p)}{\varepsilon^2 N} \to 0 \text{ as }N\to\infty.
$$

**Proof of Markov's inequality:**

Let $W=\begin{cases} y & \text{if }Y\ge y, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$

Then $0\le W\le Y$, so $\E W\le \E Y$.  And $\E W = y\Pr(Y\ge y)$. ${}\qquad\blacksquare$

Comment: Interestingly, I have usually seen these results named in reverse: Chebyshev gets attached to the "first moment" estimate and Markov gets attached to the "second moment" estimate. I have seen it this way as well, so I am not correcting you, but I still find this quirk interesting. Do you perchance know the history here?

Comment: @Ian : I've seen it only this way and never the other way. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Interesting. Maybe it's because the measure theory version of the "first moment" estimate is also attached to Chebyshev?

Comment: Perhaps.  To "attach" something to someone because it conventionally bears his name is to rely on the most unreliable source that is frequently used in the mathematical community.  Naming the "Weierstrass substitution" after Weierstrass is based on nothing; the claim in Stewart's calculus text that Weierstrass had something to do with it is based on nothing.  Pell's equation is called that because Euler mistakenly thought John Pell did something with it. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the *Weak Law of Large Numbers* (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Weak_law)) asserts that if $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\ldots$ are independent realizations of some random variable $Y$ such that $\mu=\mathbb E[Y]$, then the sample average
$$\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{Y_i}N$$
converges to the theoretical mean $\mu$ in probability.

In the context of your specific question,
find a random variable $Z$ whose mean is your probability $p$ of success,
and such that the sample average of trials of i.i.d. copies of $Z$ will be equal to $X/N$.